# Search bar in Android clarification

Tags: android, search

I've read the Android official website but still am being confused. Can I ask are searchable activity and searchable interface two different activities? My understanding is you new a intent on searchable interface activity, then pass the query to searchable activity. The searchable activity finishes the search and returns an adapter (in an usual case) to the searchable interface activity through another intent?

Is it correct?

From the website there is this snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    return true;
}
```

Shouldn't it be on the searchable interface activity? But why there is the comment above the two lines:

```
// Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
```

saying `// Assumes current activity is the searchable activity`?

Please explain. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The "Assume current Activity is searchable activity" line refers to `getComponentName()` expression (which returns the component name of the current Activity when called from within it).

> Can I ask are searchable activity and searchable interface two different activities?

You can do either way.

Searching usually happens within already displayed content, so it can be convenient to code the result filtering in the same Activity, that contains the SearchView. A new instance of the same Activity will be created and launched, each time user searches, and the previous instance can be returned to by pressing BACK. Needless to say, the Activity in question has to have suitable `launchMode` (such as default "standard") for this to work.

If you pass ComponentName of another Activity to `getSearchableInfo` like this:

```
ComponentName searchResultActivity = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), ViewerActivity.class.getName());
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(searchResultActivity));
```

then a `<meta-data>` tag within a `ViewerActivity` will be used and that Activity will receive a search Intent instead.